# color in legend with range highcharts

Tags: highcharts, range

I can not set highchart so that the color of the captions matches the colors of the series. Can you help me ? By default the current hightchart graphics do it, but with the range it does not seem to do it automatically. By the way on the highchart demo it does not do it either.

Link to a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yucca/fdwa682p/8/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'xrange'
},
title: {
    text: 'Highcharts X-range'
},
xAxis: {
    //type: 'datetime'
    //categories: [ '1','2'],
    min: 0,
    max: 6,
    title: {
                                text: "Ghz",
                                align: "high"
                            },

},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    categories: ['Prototyping', 'Development', 'Testing'],
    reversed: true
},
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    grouping: false
  }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Allocated for IMT/official plans',
     pointPadding: 0,
     groupPadding: 0,
     color: '#123456',
     showInLegend :true,
  //  borderColor: 'gray',
    //pointWidth: 20,
    data: [{
        x: 0.7,
        x2: 0.8,
        y: 0,
        color: '#123456',
        //partialFill: 0.25
    }, {
        x: 3.4,
        x2: 3.6,
        y: 0,
        color: '#123456',
    }, {
        x: 3.3,
        x2: 3.6,
        y: 1,
        color: '#123456',
    }, {
        x: 4.8,
        x2: 5.0,
        y: 1,
        color: '#123456',
   }]
}, {
    name: 'Considered',
     pointPadding: 0,
     groupPadding: 0,
     color: 'red',
     showInLegend :true,
  //  borderColor: 'gray',
    //pointWidth: 20,
    data: [{
        x: 4.4,
        x2: 4.5,
        y: 1,
        color: 'red',
        //partialFill: 0.25
    }, {
        x: 5.9,
        x2: 6,
        y: 0,
        color: 'red',
    }, {
        x: 3.3,
        x2: 3.6,
        y: 1,
        color: '#123456',
    }, {
        x: 4.8,
        x2: 5.0,
        y: 1,
        color: '#123456',
   }]
}]

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to achieve the effect you expecting, you need to apply a little `Legend.prototype.getAllItems` override:

```
(function(H) {
  H.Legend.prototype.getAllItems = function () {
                var allItems = [];
                H.each(this.chart.series, function (series) {
                    var seriesOptions = series && series.options;
                    if (series.type === 'xrange') {
                        series.color = series.userOptions.color
                    }
                    // Handle showInLegend. If the series is linked to another series,
                    // defaults to false.
                    if (series && H.pick(
                        seriesOptions.showInLegend,
                        !H.defined(seriesOptions.linkedTo) ? undefined : false, true
                    )) {

                        // Use points or series for the legend item depending on
                        // legendType
                        allItems = allItems.concat(
                            series.legendItems ||
                            (
                                seriesOptions.legendType === 'point' ?
                                    series.data :
                                    series
                            )
                        );
                    }
                });

                H.fireEvent(this, 'afterGetAllItems', { allItems: allItems });

                return allItems;
            }
})(Highcharts)
```

Then, the color defined in your series should be fill the legend item dot.
It should work only with `xrange` series, so you don't have to worry about the charts with other series, which are placed in your app.
Also you can use do it in other way, by adding **CSS** selector and set it just like that:

```
.highcharts-legend-item.highcharts-series-0 .highcharts-point {
  fill: red !important;
}
.highcharts-legend-item.highcharts-series-1 .highcharts-point {
  fill: blue !important;
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/y7xp4w8u/

Live example (CSS only): https://jsfiddle.net/xmornj1u/

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the chart is in a page which contains others. How to make the function does not affect other hightchart chart? There are no easier solutions? This comes from the way I provided my series?

Comment: If your page contains the other chart, there will be necessary to add short condition to existing function override. It should work only for all charts with `xrange` type, or you want to use it with some specific chart?
Of course there are other options (e.g by adding new CSS definition), but this one looks most universal, because everything what you set inside of the series, should be processed, and colors are added automatically. I eddited my post above, and extend it by the CSS solution.

Comment: Thanks again. Both solutions work well. In the case of my project I think I will use the css solution, with style sheets generated by some php code. Have a nice day.